# Can't Find Link in Mink

Tags: phantomjs, mink

I'm trying to find a link by using the `findLink()` method of the `NodeElement` class. The element I'm initiating the Search on, has the following inner html:

```
<div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
<h3 class="popover-title">really_confirm_forecast</h3>
<div class="popover-content text-center"><div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-apply="confirmation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
         yes</a>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-dismiss="confirmation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
         no</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm calling findLink like this:

```
$element->findLink('yes');
```

I have successfully ussed `findButton` on Elements containing `button` elements with **similar** (the difference being that the text ('yes') is wrapped inside a `div` element) Structure to the `a` Element specified above.
I'm using Mink with the [phantomjs driver](https://github.com/jcalderonzumba/MinkPhantomJSDriver).

#### Update

I can find the Link Element by calling `$element->find('named', ['content', 'yes']);`

Comment: If it's a popover you might need to either do the actual popover or, what I had to do, which was remove that class when clicking things inside it and make sure it's visible, then readd the class afterward.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No it is not. The link is **not** inside an Iframe, and the popover is displayed using **bootstrap popovers** . The important thing is that I can capture the popover element as whole in mink (`$element` above), but finding the link using `findLink()` does not work on it. The html in the question is what is returned by `$element->getHtml()`.